# Airflow Sensor for AWS ECS Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ecs

I am currently using MWAA (AWS Managed Airflow Service) and triggering an ECS Task Definition (pre-created) from a DAG running on it. I want to get the status of triggered ECS task from Airflow.

Similar to how EMR has operators through which I can create JobFlow and Steps, then attach [sensors](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/emr/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr.EmrContainerSensor) to get failed/success/in-progress status of the Airflow task. I want to replicate the same for ECS Tasks, but there aren't any sensors present on Airflow docs. If I had to create a custom ECS Task sensor, would I need to implement a custom ECS Hook also like [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/emr.py#L27). Any references or leads on this would also help.

Comment: I opened a task in airflow https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/24826 to review the source code related in that area.